# Backbone and Laravel: How to convert a JSON object

Tags: php, json, backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

From my Backbone application, Laravel is receiving the results from a POST request like this:

```
$input = Input::json();
```

This returns a JSON object, not a string.  I thought I could just use `json_decode` to get to its properties, but `json_decode` expects a string.  So how can I convert my JSON object into something where PHP can work with its properties?

I tried getting `Input::all()` from the application, but that returns an empty array.

I've tried search Google and couldn't find anything on how to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode($string)` must receive a json string as a parameter. 
By default it will return an instance of `StdClass` (object)  with all propetires (unless you dont set second parameter = true) on success and `null` on failure.

Also such values as `null`, `false`, `true` can be returned as they are.

`json_encode($anyData)` can receive in fact any data and will return a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request::getContent()` to get the requested data. With it, you can pass it to `json_decode()` as you like.

Comment: @Ulterior -- Are you saying `Request::getContent()` is "empty," or the result of `json_decode()` is "empty"?